# Using relationships to search in DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I am starting learning DBIx::Class and I have a doubt in searching in a related table:

Consider the following code:

```
 my $books = $author->search_related('books', { name => 'Titanic' }); 
 my $books = $author->books->search({name => 'Titanic'});
```

What I want is to only searches for books named 'Titanic' by the author in `$author`.
This two searches return the same resultset?
If yes, what is the best way and why?
If no, what is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`search_related` is a Resultset method.  You'd use that if you had a resultset of Authors and you wanted to get a resultset of all of their books named 'Titanic'.

```
my $books = $schema->resultset('Author')->search({ last_name => 'Smith' })
    ->search_related('books', { name => 'Titanic' });
```

If `$author` is a row object, representing one row, then your second line is how you'd search his books.

```
my $books = $author->books->search({ name => 'Titanic' });
```

The distinction between rows and resultsets is one of the core concepts of DBIx::Class. You might want to review the [DBIC Manual Intro](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Manual::Intro). #dbix-class on irc.perl.org is usually pretty active so you can find help there as well.